# Percentage column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

thanks for all help you providing me.
i need percentage column  in SQL. i tried 2 ways but unable to get.

```
SELECT distinct(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) AS latitudeModels,
       count(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) AS COUNT,
  (SELECT sum(count(*))
   FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias
   WHERE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%'
   GROUP BY v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.model0)
FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias
WHERE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%'
GROUP BY v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.model0
```

used subquery to get data in percentage error iam getting

```
    Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

now iam using second query but iam finding all 100% columns to percent column

```
SELECT distinct(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) AS latitudeModels,
       count(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) AS COUNT,
       (count(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) / count(*) * 100) AS percent1
FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias
WHERE v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%'
GROUP BY v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.model0
ORDER BY v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.model0
```

its giving data as

```
    latitudeModels  count   percent1
Latitude 5179   7   100
Latitude 5250   1   100
Latitude 5285   6   100
Latitude 5289   1   100
Latitude 5290   2226    100
Latitude 5290 2-in-1    57  100
Latitude 5480   10440   100
Latitude 5490   2235    100
Latitude 5580   47  100
Latitude 7280   1125    100
Latitude 7290   28  100
Latitude 7370   2   100
Latitude 7380   8   100
Latitude 7390   150 100
Latitude 7480   13  100
Latitude 7490   6   100
Latitude E4200  1   100
Latitude E4300  9   100
Latitude E4310  11  100
Latitude E5250  945 100
Latitude E5270  1665    100
Latitude E5440  18  100
Latitude E5450  4260    100
Latitude E5470  5231    100
Latitude E6220  13  100
Latitude E6230  33  100
Latitude E6320  256 100
Latitude E6330  671 100
Latitude E6400  15  100
Latitude E6410  42  100
Latitude E6420  370 100
Latitude E6430  546 100
Latitude E6440  3071    100
Latitude E64406349K0135/    1   100
Latitude E6540  1   100
Latitude E7240  283 100
Latitude E7250  763 100
Latitude E7270  1565    100
Latitude E7440  1582    100
```

iam getting all 100% can you please help

[image]

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` it works on the whole selected rows!!! Skip those redundant parentheses to make code clearer: `select distinct v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0 as latitudeModels, ...`.

Comment: i need percentage colume this is SCCM query iam running on SCCM database

Comment: You rarely never combine SELECT DISTINCT with GROUP BY, since GROUP BY returns no duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a couple of issues here to address.  As jarlh said in the comments, you don't need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` wtih a `GROUP BY` as `GROUP BY` would return no duplicate rows.  Secondly, you shouldn't use keywords as column aliases so you should change `count` to `countRows` or something that isn't reserved.

The issue at hand is that you are using `COUNT` which returns datatype `INT`.  You'll 
need to convert that value into a `DECIMAL` datatype to return the value you need.  The following should return the value you need in the `Percent` column..

```
select v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0 as latitudeModels,
count(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) as countRows,
((CAST(count(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(count(*) AS DECIMAL)) * 100) as percent1
from  v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias  
Where  v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0 like '%Latitude%' group by v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.model0
order by v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.model0
```

Based on your comment, I've added the following query.  To preserve any accuracy, you'll need to cast any `COUNT` calls to decimal, otherwise it will only return whole numbers.  Try the following:

```
SELECT a.model0,
       CAST(CAST(count(*) AS DECIMAL)/CAST((SELECT count(model0) AS cnt FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM a WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%') AS DECIMAL)) *100 AS DECIMAL(18,5)) AS percent1 
FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM a WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%' GROUP BY a.model0
```

Comment: i have used following query but no success SELECT model0,count(*)/(SELECT count(model0) AS cnt
                 FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM  a
                 WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%')*100 AS percent1
FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM  a
WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%'
GROUP BY a.model0  is it something we need to convert to decimal

Comment: @deepti I've added that query to my answer as it should work?

Comment: just how to reduce decimal to 5 places

Comment: @deepti you can use the parameters associated with the `DECIMAL` datatype.  The first parameter is precision, indicating how many total digits are stored -- default of 18. The second parameter is scale, indicating how many digits to store to the right of the decimal point.  So `...AS DECIMAL(18,5)` should do it.

Comment: SELECT a.model0,
       (CAST(count(*) AS DECIMAL(18,5))/CAST((SELECT count(model0) AS cnt FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM a WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%') AS DECIMAL(18,5))) *100 AS percent1 
FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM a WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%' GROUP BY a.model0 its not working

Comment: Hmmm.. You may need to cast the entire expression as `DECIMAL(18,5)`.  `CAST((CAST(count(*) AS DECIMAL)/CAST((SELECT count(model0) AS cnt FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM a WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%') AS DECIMAL)) *100 AS DECIMAL(18,5)) AS percent1`

Comment: SELECT 
    CAST((CAST(count(*) AS DECIMAL(18,5))/
  CAST((SELECT count(model0) AS cnt FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM a WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%') AS DECIMAL(18,5))) *100 as DECIMAL(18,5))
FROM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM a WHERE a.Model0 LIKE '%Latitude%' GROUP BY a.model0 worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply the 100 to the denominator.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) AS latitudeModels,
count(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) as count,
(CAST(count(v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(count(*) AS DECIMAL)) * 100 as percent1
 from  v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias  
 Where  v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.Model0 like '%Latitude%' 
 group by v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.model0
 order by v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_Alias.model0
```

Comment: still getting same data